# What's the difference between casting and coercing a pointer in swift?

Tags: swift, pointers, void-pointers

Motivation is trying to use a callback with a C API where I pass in anything I want through a void pointer.

So suppose I have an `x: UnsafePointer<Void>`. I know what it *really* is, so I want to convert the pointer appropriately. What is the difference between using unsafeBitCast, or just applying UnsafePointer to x? In other words

Is

```
let y = unsafeBitCast(x, to: UnsafePointer<MyStruct>.self)
```

different from

```
let z = UnsafePointer<MyStruct>(x)
```

in some way?

Comment: For the sake of using the C API, it might be good to wrap the C API in a very thin Swift layer in which you do this unsafe mapping from void pointers to Swift values.  The rest of your code then goes through your Swift code and your code base isn't littered with this very precarious code--it's all collected into a single set of wrapper code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsafeBitCast` is an unsafe conversion between **any** two Swift types of the same size. That is, you can write `unsafeBitCast(x, UnsafePointer<MyStruct>.self)`, but you could have also written `unsafeBitCast(x, MyClass.self)` or `unsafeBitCast(x, Int.self)`. This is generally very unsafe, because Swift doesn't guarantee much about the memory layout of its types. Using UnsafePointer or [Unmanaged](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Unmanaged_Structure/index.html) might be better options in your case.

The "coercion" `UnsafePointer<MyStruct>(x)` isn't really a special language feature, it's just [an UnsafePointer initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_UnsafePointer_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structctr/UnsafePointer/s:FSPcurFGSPqd___GSPx_) which takes another UnsafePointer. Its effect is to reinterpret the value at the same memory address as a different type, similar to casting between pointer types in C (or `static_cast`ing in C++). The conversion between the two Swift types (the two variants of UnsafePointer) is safe, but of course they are still **Unsafe**Pointers, so you must be certain you're accessing the memory correctly; you are still responsible for allocation and deallocation.

Comment: Which is to say, once you access the `memory` property of the `UnsafePointer` you're in the same position as having `unsafeBitCast` it, right?

Comment: Are there any performance implications between the two? Are they both effectively free?

Comment: Yes, they should be, especially when you have optimization turned on.